# Creating a Trigger which will insert record in a table on update of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

Suppose I have tables T1 and T2

```
Columns of T1 -->Value
Columns of T2 -->OldValue NewValue
```

What I require is a trigger which will insert a record in T2 on updation of T1 , I need to know the old value and new value also , I have never used triggers before , so can any help me with this , how do I go about creating this trigger.Is it possible ,thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you start writing a trigger with `CREATE TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NameOfTheTriggerPlease
…
```

The table that should trigger the additional action is `T1` so the trigger should be defined `ON` that table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1OnUpdate  /* that's just an example,
                              you can use a different name */
ON T1
…
```

The action that the trigger should be invoked on is `UPDATE` and the timing is `AFTER` the update, so…

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1OnUpdate
ON T1
AFTER UPDATE
…
```

Now's the time to introduce the *body* of the trigger, i.e. the statements that should actually be executed by the trigger. You introduce the body with the `AS` keyword followed by the statements themselves.

In your case, there would be just one statement, `INSERT`, which is obvious. What's not so obvious is how we are going to access the old and the new values. Now, SQL Server offers you two virtual tables, `INSERTED` and `DELETED`, and you can easily guess that the former contains all the new values and the latter the old ones.

These tables have the same structure as the table the trigger is assigned to, i.e. `T1`. They only contain rows that were affected by the particular `UPDATE` statement that invoked the trigger, which means there may be more than one. And that, in turn, means that you need to have some primary key or a unique column (or a set of columns) in your `T1` table that you can use in the trigger to match deleted and inserted rows. (In fact, you might also need your `T2` table to have a column that would reference the `T1`'s primary key, so you could later establish which row of `T1` had which values stored in `T2`.)

For the purposes of this answer, I'm going to assume that there's a primary key column called `PK` and a foreign key column of the same name in `T2`. And the `INSERT` statement then might look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1OnUpdate
ON T1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
INSERT INTO T2 (PK, OldValue, NewValue)
SELECT i.PK, i.Value, d.Value
FROM INSERTED i INNER JOIN DELETED d ON i.PK = d.PK
```

One last (but not least) thing to remember: the entire `CREATE TRIGGER` statement should be the only one in the batch, i.e. there should be no statements preceding the `CREATE TRIGGER` keywords (but you can put comments there) and, likewise, everything after the `AS` keyword is considered part of the trigger's body (but you can put the `GO` delimiter to indicate the end of the statement if you are running the script in SQL Server Management Studio, for instance).

Useful reading:

- [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: suppose T1 has many fields and out of them only few are updated , so do you think I will get only fields which are updated.thanks for your help.

Comment: Both `inserted` and `deleted` will contain all the columns. The unaffected values will be present in both tables, the affected ones will differ accordingly.

Comment: here I have only one field Value , if I have many fields , then how do I get new values for all columns , any hints

Comment: Not sure I understand what troubles you, sorry. Either `inserted` or `deleted` will have as many columns as there is in `T1`. You can reference any of those columns in `inserted`, which will be the value(s) *after* the update, while referencing the same column(s) in `deleted` will give you the value(s) *before* the update. The `SELECT` clause in the above `INSERT` statement could be anything like this: `SELECT i.PK, i.Column1, Column2, …, d.Column1, d.Column2, …`. Like I said, some values in `inserted` will be the same as the corresponding values in `deleted` if the update didn't change them.

Comment: @Andiry I was asking that if I wanted to know which all columns were update then will I have to write i.col1,i.col2,i.col3,...... and so on till my last column.Hope you understand what I am asking

Comment: @freebird: You mean, you want to log every changed column in a separate row? Like, look at col1, if it changed, then store old col1 as OldValue and new col1 as NewValue, otherwise skip; then look at col2, and if it changed, store old col2 as OldValue and new col2 as NewValue, otherwise skip; and so on; is that correct?

Comment: ya for every column changed I need a row in my other table , you are right , is it possible.

Comment: @freebird: If col1 is a number and col2 is a date/time, then the answer is, no. But if the columns which you want to track are of the same type, then yes, it is possible, although approaches to solving this may be different.

Comment: @freebird. Regarding the case when the types are different: actually, it *would* be possible, but you'd have to convert the values into strings, I think.

Comment: @Andiry so I need to convert it into string and then store it right ??

Comment: @Andiry , could guide me for my problem , I have many tables , my client wants that if any column in any table is modified , it should have a record in a history table which stores the name of table whose column is modified, column which is modified , old value and new value, how do I go about it , should I use a trigger per table or any other approach , pls point me thanks a lot.

Comment: @freebird: Personally, I would most likely try to solve this with multiple triggers (one trigger per table), but I am not sure that would really be the best approach. Although I can roughly understand the extent of your problem, I have never encountered anything like it in practice, and so, if I had to solve this kind of problem, I myself might need a guidance. I suggest you ask this as a separate question (a little tip: if you are unsure how to describe things, try giving examples of what you want). I'm sure there are people on SO more experienced in this area than I am.

Comment: @freebird: Also, try searching this site for ready answers, try `[sql-server] table audit` or maybe `[sql-server] audit triggers` in the search box.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to build the whole thing for you (no fun, right?) but I can point you in the right direction

```
create trigger logUpdate
on T1
After update
as
begin
  insert into T2...
  --here is just an example
  select * from deleted --the DELETED table contains the OLD values
  select * from inserted  --the INSERTED table contains the NEW values
end
```

remember that DELETED and INSERTED are internal tables that contains old and new values. On a update trigger, they both exist. On a insert trigger, DELETED will be null because there is nothing being delete. Same logic on a delete trigger, the INSERTED will be empty

EDIT:

answering your question: no matter how many fields you update, your DELETED and INSERTED tables you have all the columns of all the rows affected. Of course, if you update only one column, all the other will have the same value on DELETED and INSERTED

Comment: thank you , I have a question that if my T1 table contains many fields , and out of them only few are modified , so the select * from deleted statement will give only the updated ones , is it.Any links you can point me for further help.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
create trigger T_UPD_T1
on T1 FOR  update
as
insert into T2 select deleted.value, inserted.value from inserted, deleted
```

Comment: deleted.value will be the old value , is it ?