# Trigger- insert on one table updates other

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert, sql-update

I need to use a trigger to update a stock table after inserting on a offers table. In the stock table it should let us know the stock available from the offers at any time.
The tables are

[image]

It's the OFERTA table, a dependent table ITEMSOFERT and the Table Stock

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Trigger which will insert record in a table on update of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648983/creating-a-trigger-which-will-insert-record-in-a-table-on-update-of-another-tabl)

Comment: @Will i've tried some things but it's not really a great help, i'm really clueless...

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far and where you are getting stuck. SO is not a general how-to site, but we're more than happy to help answer [specific questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please post the schema , sample data and expected result in text not image.